# Checking the continuity of the given function at the point $(1,0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

$$f(x,y) = \frac{3y(x-1)}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$$

so knowing that function is continuous when it has a limit. I will applying a two path test to check that.

$$f(x,0)\to (1,0) = \frac{0(x-1)}{(x-1)^2+0} = 0 $$

and

$$f(x,x-1)\to (1,0) = \frac{3(x-1)(x-1)}{(x-1)^2+(x-1)^2} =  \frac{3(x-1)^2}{2(x-1)^2}= 3/2$$

so is this function discontinous?

Comment: To have continuity you need more than just the limit existing.  The function also has to be defined at that point and equal to the limit.  $f(x,y)$ is not even defined at $(1,0)$ so $f(x,y)$ is definitely not continuous at $(1,0)$.  Are you just trying to show whether or not the limit exists?  You've correctly shown it doesn't although the notation looks very unusual and hard to decipher at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since it approaches different values depending on the direction of the limit, the function is discontinuous.

The 1D analog behavior would be when
$$
\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) \ne \lim_{x \to a^-} f(x),
$$
in which case we also say $f$ is discontinuous at $a$, and the discontinuity is essential, or non-removable.